# Unexpected error occurs with PDO select query and not showing the result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I am learning PDO and now I have a problem with my code but I am not able to find that out. It is not showing the result. Please point out my mistake.

```
        $user=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, strip_tags($_POST['username']));
        $pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, strip_tags($_POST['password']));

        $que1="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Email`=?";

      $result = $mysqli->prepare($que1);
      $result->bind_param(1, $user);
      $result->execute();

      $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      echo $row["user_id"];
```

Comment: See a **proper** [PDO select example](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select#prepare)

Comment: Is it PDO, or is it mysqli? You seem to be using aspects of both.

Comment: U have to use PDO if you want to work with PDO, and mysqli when u want mysqli. Don't confuse this, PDO ist oop - style, thus called like $myobject->execute(); while mysqli uses parametrised function calls that are kindof static. Nowadays always use PDO!

Comment: @clockw0rk mysqli uses object syntax as well, and it is recommended